# Repeat a function 3 times, but each time change .animation

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, repeat

I have a bunch of div's stacked on a main div called: `#deck`. If I click `#deck`, the top div will move to the left and will have some classes added (like: `.addClass('on-discard-pile')`).

If I click `#deck` again, the next top div will move to the left on top of the previous div. I have the following working code for this:

```
    var z = 1;
    $('#deck .card.flipped').on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('dropped')) {
            $('.card').removeClass('ui-front');
            $(this)
                .addClass('ui-front')
                .addClass('on-discard-pile')
                .addClass('dropped')
                .css({'z-index': z++})
                .animate({left: '8rem'}, 200)
                .draggable({ disabled: false})
                .removeClass('flipped');

            set(moveCount, moveCount.value + 1);

            if (!$(this).is(':first-child')) {
                $('.card').removeClass('under-card');
                $(this).next().addClass('under-card'); 
            } else {
                $('.card').removeClass('under-card');
            }
        }
    });
```

This all works fine, but I want to change the function a bit. Instead of moving the top div, I want to move the top 3 div's from `#deck`. I don't want to move the divs on top of each other, but slightly over each other. So the first top div must move to the left `8rem`, then the sec top div to `10rem` and the last `12rem`

That's not all, the last div (going to `12rem` and having the highest z-index) should be the only div getting `.draggable({ disabled: false})`, BUT (yes another but) if I click `#deck` again the `.draggable({ disabled: false})` should be removed again and added to the new top div.

So the only the div with the highest z-index and with class `on-discard-pile` should have `.draggable({ disabled: false})`

How to do this? Did some searching on the net, looked at `loop`, `repeat`, `array` and `:lt()`, but got none working.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using "trigger": `$( '#deck .card.flipped' ).last().trigger("click",[2])`